# How can I edit a text file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms

Lets say i have a text file with following content:

> Hello!
>   How are you?

I want to call the file via a simple application that produces an output file with the following contents:

```
buildLetter.Append("Hello!").AppendLine(); 
buildLetter.Append("How are you?").AppendLine();
```

As you see, every line should be put between " ".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, this is what I use a regexp find&replace for, you can do it straight from your IDE without writing any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void ConvertFile(string inPath, string outPath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inPath))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter (outPath))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("buildLetter.Append(\"{0}\").AppendLine();",line.Trim());
            line = reader.ReadLine ();    
        }
    }
}
```

You should add some I/O exception handling on your own.

Comment: Nitpicking: You could remove a `{}` pair and an indentlevel between the using statements. This notation doesn't scale well to  to 3+ resources.

Comment: done also change !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) to line != null to handle empty lines in input file.

Comment: I will try it and let you know!

Comment: Works great! How can i ignore spaces between the word e.g. --- Hello!
so the word between quotation occurs as "   Hello!" .... How can i let the word occur as "Hello!" without spaces? .... Thanks alot

Comment: added `.Trim()` to `writer.WriteLine` it removes spaces from beginning and end of line.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append `""` to each line you could try combining the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and [WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz3b1wh.aspx) methods:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "output.txt",
    File
        .ReadAllLines("input.txt")
        .Select(line => string.Format("\"{0}\"", line))
        .ToArray()
);
```

Notice that this loads the whole file contents into memory so it wouldn't work well with very large files. In this case stream readers and writers are more adapted.

Comment: I would replace the "\"" + line + "\"" with string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "\"", line)

Answer (score 0):

Use the StreamReader class from System.IO

Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) for sample code

All you probably need to do is change the line

```
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(""""" + sr.ReadLine() + """"");  // handwritten code - not tested :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small text files this works for me.

```
private void EditFile(string path, string oldText, string newText)
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
            content = contenido.Replace(oldText, newText);
            File.WriteAllText(path, content);
        }
```